# lldb from XCode 6 not allowing C++ exception breakpoints?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, lldb

Ever since upgrading to XCode 6 I haven't been able to set exception breakpoints in lldb.

For example, given

```
class Exception {
};

int main() {
  throw Exception();
}
```

If I run it I get an exception:

```
% ./a.out
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Exception
[1]    46805 abort      ./a.out
```

However if I start up lldb

```
% lldb ./a.out
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Current executable set to './a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) break set -E c++
error: Breakpoint creation failed: No breakpoint created.
```

I haven't been able to find documentation anywhere about setting exception breakpoints changing.  Is there some new build flag I need to be using?

Comment: The following seems to work

    "break set -n __cxa_throw"

but it would be good to know why the normal method is failing

Comment: This looks like an issue with LLDB - can you please file a bug report with Apple to keep track of it?

Comment: Just guessing... did you compile and link against LLVM's ***`libc++`*** or GNU's ***`libstdc++`***?